# Можно ли как-то собрать Electron.js приложение в 1 исполняемый файл

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe, electron

В шапке вопрос, спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно, советую ознакомится с документацией по electron builder

https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis#portable

```
electron-builder --win portable
```

Успехов вам :)